# Combinations of columns, and product in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have the following data:

```
data.frame(Id=c(0,1,2,3),A=c(1,2,3,4),B=c(5,6,7,8),C=c(9,10,11,NA))
```

I need to generate all possible combinations of the values ​​of columns A, B and C, and multiply their values. That is to say,

```
1*5*9
1*5*10
1*5*11
...
1*6*9
1*6*10
...
3*4*11
```

Moreover, once I have multiplied the combinations, I have to add the products according to the variable Id (and its sum). For instance, if I have multiplied the combination 1 (A) * 5 (B) * 10 (C), the product corresponds to the Ids: 0 (A), 0 (B), 1 (C), with sum = 1. This product should be added to product 1 (A) * 6 (B) * 9 (C), that corresponds to the Ids: 0(A), 1 (B), 0 (C), with sum = 1. How could you do it efficiently? The number of possible combinations could be very high.

Kind regards,

Majesus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.grid = cbind( expand.grid(df[,rep(1,3)]), prod=apply(expand.grid(df[,2:4]), 1, prod))

> aggregate( prod ~ I(Id + Id.1 + Id.2), df.grid, sum)
#   I(Id + Id.1 + Id.2) prod
# 1                   0   45
# 2                   1  194
# 3                   2  521
# 4                   3 1056
# 5                   4 1523
# 6                   5 1738
# 7                   6 1479
# 8                   7  892
# 9                   8  352
```